# Cannot Use/Add Material Design 1 in Android Studio

Tags: java, material-design

I cannot add material design api to my app. I have tried different versions but always get the below errors.

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Test'.
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

OR

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Project'.
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

```
My gradlefile:
    
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    }


    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    }
```

I have tried sing the Shrine project from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-java#1 but get the same error as above.

I am using Android 9(Physical Device) and the Android Studio(Dolphin).

I would really appreciate any help. I was not able to find a solution for my problem on previous questions as they we not recent.